# How to quit an app that can't be stopped from the menu bar?

Tags: applications, force-quit

I need to uninstall the "mate translate" app, but cannot stop it from the menu bar: the app has no menu when I select it.

The app doesn't appear in "Force Quit" either.

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

1. Double click on the target app in Activity Monitor
2. Click "Quit > Force Quit" in the window that opens